# System.Data.Services Client: source code on GitHub

Tags: mono, xamarin.forms

I downloaded the source code of the “System.Data.Services.Client” package from the site “ https://github.com/mono/mono ”, but apparently the source code is not up-to-date, because I see that the “DataServiceContext” (source code: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data.Services.Client/Client/System/Data/Services/Client/DataServiceContext.cs ) does not have all the members listed on the site “ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext(v=vs.113).aspx ”, such as “Format” or “DefaultResolveType”. What is the reason? Is there a way to get the current source code?

Is the “System.Data.Services.Client” package compatible with Xamarin.Forms? I need to solve the problem described in my question “ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32690291/updating-a-record-in-an-odata-service-using-c-sharp ” and the only idea that I currently have is to include the source code of the “System.Data.Services.Client” package in my solution in order to see what happens in the package.

Answer (score 0):

Mono and .NET Framework is not the same thing. You are looking at source code of Mono, but then you refer to MSDN with documentation about DataServiceContext which is part of .NET Framework. Mono developers try to at least follow the same public interface, but here and there you will see differences. So if Format property is missing - that does not mean source code is "not up-to-date" because source code and documentation you are looking at belong to different projects.

Now, even in such case you may use the same source code under both Mono and .NET Framework, unless you use those missing methods\properties.